# Retrieve id based only on url

Tags: php, wordpress

Say I have a url in wordpress that looks like this: http://my-domain.com/page/34282 where 34282 is the id of a post.

What's the cleanest way to retrieve the id based only on the url (I can't do stuff like get_the_ID or $post->ID in this case). Feels kinda hacky to do a str_replace or regex, I'm hoping wordpress has something built in for this.

Comment: global $post;
$post->ID;

or

the_ID();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
$urlArr = explode("/", $url);
$id = end($urlArr);
```

Comment: This seems to be the cleanest way.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use `explode()` function to achieve this

```
$url = 'http://my-domain.com/page/34282';
$url_array = explode("/",$url);
$id = $url_array[count($url_array) - 1];
echo $id;
//print 34282
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this function:

```
function getUriSegment($n) {
    $segs = getUriSegments();
    return count($segs)>0&&count($segs)>=($n-1)?$segs[$n]:'';
}
```

Then you could use:

```
echo getUriSegment(2); // echo's ID
```

Although this is more of for PHP overall, Wordpress might have something built in.

([Source of code](http://www.timwickstrom.com/server-side-code/php/php-get-uri-segments/))